# Euclidean Fifth Postulate

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

When did Euclidean Fifth Postulate comes to be called the Parallel Postulate? It is taken for granted. Did Euclid refer to the fifth postulate as the Parallel Postulate?

Answer (score 0):

The fifth postulate does not specifically talk about parallel lines, it is only a postulate related to parallelism. Euclid gave the definition of parallel lines in Book I, Definition 23 just before the five postulates.
However, we see that there is the following equivalence:

[Equivalence to the Euclidean Parallel Postulate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199689/equivalence-to-the-euclidean-parallel-postulate?rq=1)

About the history of the fifth postulate see the article

[History of the Parallel Postulate](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2973238?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by Florence P. Lewis.

Comment: But who first thought the fifth postulate addressed the problem of parallel lines?

Comment: I think it is answered in the article about the history about the fifth postulate.

Comment: Thanks I am going to re-read it carefully. I scanned it. It seems to me that Euclid did not call it a parallel postulate. So he shouldn't be accused of begging any questions

Comment: Doesn't parallel lines get proven later when parallel planes get transacted by a transversal plane?

Comment: Article ...thanks